# How can I get the value of a checkbox using jquery and name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have this code :

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0 d1"
                              name="d1" checked="checked">
```

And actually I would want to show an alert using the name which is d1 to know if the case is checked or not.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('[name="d1"]')` to select element using name

```js
console.log($('[name="d1"]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0 d1"
                              name="d1" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `name` selector you can get value using `val()`  function

```js
console.log($('[name="d1"]').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0 d1" name="d1" checked="checked" value="abc">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[name='d1']:checkbox").change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
alert('it is checked');
else 
alert('no it is not checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0 d1"
                              name="d1" checked>
```

You can specify the input name, and add listener.